# Custom Map Pin on Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm following the article by Xamarin that describes how to customize a pin using an image [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin)

```
 protected override MarkerOptions CreateMarker(Pin pin)
 {
var marker = new MarkerOptions();
marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Position.Longitude));
marker.SetTitle(pin.Label);
marker.SetSnippet(pin.Address);
marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.pin));
return marker;
}
```

I have a png image in resources/drawable.  However, the map does not show any pins.  I put a breakpoint in the custom renderer and it hits so I know its being called.  Here is the code for the page that implements the custom map:

Xaml

```
 <controls:CustomMap MapType="Street" x:Name="map" WidthRequest="150"  IsVisible="True" HasZoomEnabled="True" HasScrollEnabled="True">
                        <controls:CustomMap.HeightRequest>
                            <OnIdiom>
                                <OnIdiom.Phone>
                                    <OnPlatform
                                iOS="250"
                                Android="150" />
                                </OnIdiom.Phone>
                            </OnIdiom>
                        </controls:CustomMap.HeightRequest>
                    </controls:CustomMap>
```

and the code behind

```
  var position = new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(item.Latitude.Value, item.Longitude.Value); // Latitude, Longitude
                        var pin = new CustomPin
                        {
                            Type = PinType.Place,
                            Position = position,
                            Label = item.Name,
                            Address = item.AddressString
                        };

                        pin.Clicked += async (sender, e) =>
                        {
                            await Navigation.PushAsync(new RestaurantDetails(item));
                        };

                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                        {
                            map.Pins.Add(pin);
                            map.CustomPins.Add(pin);
                            // map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(position, Distance.FromMiles(0.3)));
                        });
```

Comment: is BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource returning a value?

Comment: Yes its returning a value

Comment: This is solved, didn't put the images also in the drawable-xxxx folders.  UGH!

Answer (score 0):

This is solved, didn't put the images also in the drawable-xxxx folders. UGH!

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was the **CustomMap** class which I was adding the **CustomPins** to did not raise the **CreateMarker** overridden method.

It may help someone else to know that you may see this same issue where the Pins do not appear on your **CustomMap** if you are adding your **CustomPin** objects to the **CustomPin** collection. I was able to fix this by adding each of them to the Pins collection as well.